# Importing mesh as a blend shape

Tags: shape-keys

I have two versions of the same object, with one morphed in a different shape. Is there a way to import the base obj in Blender, and the other one as a shape key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After importing the two objects in the same scene, select the shaped, shift select the base object and in the properties panel, shape key tab, select "Join as shapes".

The two objects must have the same list of vertices in order to work properly (they have to be one the modified copy of the other).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.